# ¿Cómo almacenar datos de MySQL en variables para uso global?

Tags: php, mysql, funciones, variables

Buenas a todos, tengo una duda que ha acabado con todos mis intentos... Verán, tengo una función en PHP que extrae datos de una tabla llamada *"c_configs"* la cual contiene 5 columnas; lo que me gustaría hacer es obtener los datos de esa tabla y después almacenarlos en sus respectivas variables. Lo que hago normalmente es obener los datos mediante un *While* o un *for* (según el caso) pero tengo problemas al asignarle a cada "dato" una variable.

```
function getConfigs() {

    $q = "SELECT * FROM c_configs";
    $r = $mysqli->query($q);

    return $r;

}
```

Luego mediante otra función trato de hacer esa asignación...

```
function fsConfigs(){

    $this->settings = $this->getConfigs();

}
```

Comment: y cual es el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imaginemos que la tabla `c_configs` tiene un solo registro, cuyo contenido es

```
timeout | color | name  |  prefix
______________________________
1000    | red   | myapp |  app
```

Luego,

```
SELECT * FROM c_configs
```

Devuelve un solo registro. Cuando haces

```
function getConfigs() {
    $q = "SELECT * FROM c_configs";
    $r = $mysqli->query($q);

    return $r;
}
```

En este momento, `$r` es un objeto del tipo [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php) y, por lo que describes, tú quieres el contenido de ese result. Luego debieras hacer:

```
function getConfigs() {
    $q = "SELECT * FROM c_configs";
    $r = $mysqli->query($q);
    $filas = $r->fetch_all(FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $filas[0];
}
```

Entonces cuando haces

```
function fsConfigs(){

    $this->settings = $this->getConfigs();

}
```

El valor de `$this->settings` es

```
[
'timeout' => 1000,
'color'   => 'red',
'name'    => 'myapp',
'prefix'  => 'app'
]
```

**Nota:**

Si la tabla `c_configs` tuviese en cambio dos columnas y cada tupla tuviese la forma `(llave, valor)`:

```
llave   | valor
________________
timeout | 1000
color   | red
name    | myapp
prefix  | app
```

entonces el código es distinto:

```
function getConfigs() {
    $q = "SELECT * FROM c_configs";
    $r = $mysqli->query($q);
    $filas = $r->fetch_all(FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $filas;
}
```

En ese caso `$this->settings` sería

```
[
  ['llave'=>'timeout'  , 'valor' => '1000'],
  ['llave' => 'color'  , 'valor' => 'red',],
  ['llave' => 'name'   , 'valor' => 'myapp',],
  ['llave' => 'prefix' , 'valor' => 'app'],
]
```

Lo cual probablemente no es lo que quieres y tengas que hacer un bucle igual.

Comment: Carajo! Gracias amigo, comprendí muchas cosas con tu respuesta, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder, muy agradecido :)

Answer (score 1):

no entiendo que hace esa función... tampoco le quiero metere mente...

pero puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "world");

    /* comprobar la conexión */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $consulta = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

    if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {

        /* obtener el array de objetos */
        unset($variable1);
        unset($variable2);
        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_row()) {
             $variable1[] = $fila[0];
             $variable2[] = $fila[1];
        }

        /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
        $resultado->close();
    }

    /* cerrar la conexión */
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

hay más ejemplos en la página de php.

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Saludos.